# Keep table aspect ratio when window is resized

Tags: jquery, html, css, resize, fullcalendar

I have been having this problem for a little bit now..

I have created a rough 'mock-up' of what I am working with.
If you take a look at the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/URwpA/10/), you will see that the 'calendar'(table) is not being contained within it's parent div (the 'orange' div)

**What do I need to do, so that the table is always contained within it's parent element each time the window is resized?**

**It must do this without creating scroll bars while maintaining 10px from the top, left, bottom and right sides of the parent element?**

http://jsfiddle.net/URwpA/10/

All help is very much appreciated!

Comment: May be `overflow: auto;` to `#hold` is what you are looking for.. http://jsfiddle.net/URwpA/16/ What do you mean by without scrollbars.. You can use `overflow: hidden` if you don't want scroll bars but that would just hide the exceeding content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about http://jsfiddle.net/URwpA/26/

Basically, remove all widths and heights in pixels from the HTML, and add `td, th {height:16%}` to the CSS. (I also cleaned up a bit by removing the `style` attribute from `<div class="held">`, because it clashed with the style in the CSS block.)

Answer (score 0):

well firstly your css is referencing an id for held (`#held`) when it should actually be a class (`.held`)

The other thing is by using `position:absolute` you are removing the div `hold` from the flow context, which is why the orange background isn't extending to the bottom.
Take this away and it works:
http://jsfiddle.net/DigitalBiscuits/URwpA/22/

is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I am looking to have the calendar contained within it's parent. If you scroll down in your example, you can see that it is escaping. Next I am looking to have the table 'scale' with the window resize so that the table is always fully visible within the window.

Check this as an example. Now if there were a table based calendar within the 'held' element it would need to stay within those bounds and look the same when resized. http://jsfiddle.net/URwpA/24/ (resize your browser window to see what I mean.) Thanks!

Comment: @captainrad If you want your table to scale with the container, why do your cells all have fixed widths and heights in pixels?

Comment: @MrLister good point! What would be the best route? set minimum and maximum heights and widths?

Comment: To get rid of those pixels and use percentages. See my answer.